# clearInterval doesn't work for me

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var waveTimes = 0;
var detectInterval = setInterval(function(){
    if(parseInt($(".people").css("top")) > 420){
        var waveInterval = setInterval(peopleWave,300);
        clearInterval(detectInterval);
    }
},300);
function peopleWave(){
    waveTimes += 1;
    if(waveTimes == 6){
        clearInterval(waveInterval);
    }
    var pic1 = "images/index/wave1.png";
    var pic2 = "images/index/wave2.png";
    if($(".wave img").attr("src") == pic1){
        $(".wave img").attr("src",pic2);
    } else {
        $(".wave img").attr("src",pic1);
    }
}
```

it says waveInterval not found after peopleWave runs 6 times, how can I solve it?

Comment: `waveInterval` is not in scope in `peopleWave`

Comment: `waveInterval` is defined in your anonymous function. `peopleWave` doesn't have access to it.

Comment: @BillCriswell what is that even supposed to mean?

Comment: @Zack: I expect it's related to the "doesn't work **for me**" aspect of the title.

Comment: @BillCriswell It's not like yukinari is stating that it *should* work for them, just that they can't figure out *why* it isn't working for them.

Comment: I wasn't being that serious Zack. =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define `waveInterval` outside your anonymous function, so that `peopleWave` has access to it:

```
var waveTimes = 0,
    waveInterval;
...
waveInterval = setTimeout(peopleWave, 300);
```

Comment: im newbie in javascript / jquery and i didnt even know that "setTimeout" syntax!
thank you so much!